# How can i define a mysql connection in Zend's application.ini file?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am new to Zend Framework. I want to initialize connection configration of zend and phpmyadmin.
Whats the code for that?

Answer (score 6):

This connection is not between Zend and phpmyadmin. It is **Zend-MySQL** connection.

Please read following article. It includes basic information that how to connect to MySQL with Zend:

- [Create a Model and Database Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html)

Here is a sample of **application.ini** database configuration:

```
[production]
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "mysqlhost"
resources.db.params.username = "mysqlusername"
resources.db.params.password = "mysqlpassword"
resources.db.params.dbname = "databasename"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "mysite"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
;resources.db.params.profiler = true ;if you use profiler
```